# Error while putting something in my array. C

Tags: c, arrays, struct, realloc

My program (Eclipse Neon) crashes while I run my program. I found the line with the problem, but I don't know how to solve it.

First I make a dynamic array:

```
int nLeden = 0;
AtletiekLid *ledenArray = (AtletiekLid *)calloc(nLeden, sizeof(AtletiekLid));
```

with this struct:

```
typedef struct {
    char naam[30];
    unsigned leeftijd;
} AtletiekLid;
```

After that I do this:

```
AtletiekLid lid;

strcpy(&lid.naam, "Test");
strcpy(&lid.leeftijd, "18");
addLid(ledenArray, lid, nLeden); //Program stopped working (windows error) on this line.
```

the `addLid` function:

```
void addLid(AtletiekLid **ledenArray, AtletiekLid lid, int *nLeden) {   
    *ledenArray = (AtletiekLid *)realloc(*ledenArray, (*nLeden + 1) * sizeof(AtletiekLid));
    (*ledenArray)[*nLeden] = lid;
    (*nLeden)++;
}
```

In the `addLid` (where my program crashed) it crashed on this line:

```
*ledenArray = (AtletiekLid *)realloc...
```

Can someone help me, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `strcpy(&lid.leeftijd, "18");` -> `lid.leeftijd = 18`. Don't ignore compiler warnings.

Comment: never use the same pointer variable as left hand side assignment to a `realloc` call.

Comment: @MichaelWalz this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @NoëlVissers there are other problems as well, for example `addLid(ledenArray, lid, &nLeden);` -> `addLid(&ledenArray, lid, &nLeden);`

Comment: @MichaelWalz Thanks! This solved my problem!

Comment: Also: Don't cast the return values from calloc and realloc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 errors in the code fragment posted:

- `strcpy(&lid.naam, "Test");` should read `strcpy(lid.naam, "Test");` as `lid.naam` is an array that decays into a pointer to its first element when passed to a function.
- `strcpy(&lid.leeftijd, "18");` is incorrect. `lid.leeftijd` is an `unsigned int`, you should instead write `lid.leeftijd = 18;`
- `addLid(ledenArray, lid, nLeden);` is incorrect too as `addLid` expects a pointer to a pointer as its first argument and a pointer to the number of elements as the third, so it can update these in the caller's scope.  You should write this instead: `addLid(&ledenArray, lid, &nLeden);`

Note that you should compile your program with more warnings enabled to let the compiler issue useful diagnostics about this kind of type mismatches.